# Joomla 3x - Profile Fields

Tags: mysql, joomla

I have added a checkbox to the user profile and need to know how to get a list of all the user email addresses where they have checked the checkbox. I would like to just run a SQL query, but can't see where the value is stored.

Comment: Please make sure you post your code, what you have tried and what issue you are facing. Otherwise, the question would be closed since it wouldn't adhere to stackoverflow rules.

Comment: You need to explain how you added the field.

Comment: Adding the field is a normal function of the Joomla 3.x Admin interface - I did not need to do anything (How to add a checkbox to a user profile was not what the question was about)

Answer (score 0):

All the profile data is stored in #__user_profiles table. To retrieve the data from the profile table you can perform this query

```
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with "checkbox.".
// Order it by the ordering field.
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('user_id', 'profile_key', 'profile_value')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('profile_key') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('\'checkbox.%\''));

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

You will get object list of all those users who clicked on your checkbox. Remember to use the profile_key name in place of `checkbox`

Comment: Thanks Amit - that is what I would have expected, but that is not how it appears to work. The user_profile table contains only records to another text value which I added to the profile (profile_postal_code) which works as you describe. I have added a checkbox (both in a field group and also with no field group) I can view the value when opening the user in the Joomla Admin page and as a user looking at my profile, but can't see where/how this is stored in the SQL table

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I have now managed to answer my own question (I took an export of the database as a SQL file, ticked the checkbox as a test user, made another export and then compared the files to see what had changed).

The values are stored in the jos_fields_values table. The query below assumes that there is only one checkbox - if you have more than one you will need to query the field_id as well, Replace xxx with the prefix of your Joomla installation.

SELECT email FROM xxx_users INNER JOIN xxx_fields_values ON xxx_users.ID=xxx_fields_values.item_id